# How to properly update Intel microcode in Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, intel, microcode

I want to update my cpu microcode to the latest version and the steps I follow to do that are as below

```
sudo apt-get install microcode.ctl intel-microcode
```

First I executed the command above and I got the output below:

```
[sudo] password for nuc: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
microcode.ctl is already the newest version (1.18~0+nmu2).
intel-microcode is already the newest version (3.20191115.1ubuntu0.18.04.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Then I rebooted my intel-nuc machine and then executed the command below:

```
dmesg | grep microcode
```

What I got as the output is:

```
[    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xca, date = 2019-10-03
[    1.223192] microcode: sig=0x906e9, pf=0x8, revision=0xca
[    1.223243] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
```

From this output I understand that my microcode version is not updated to the latest version, and I thought that is the right way to do that, but I guess I am missing something here.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Microcode will be updated along with regular system updates when they are available in the Ubuntu repository.

Comment: It IS getting updated early in the boot cycle, as seen by "microcode updated early to revision 0xca". Although you indicate there's a newer version available, for now, with this release of intel-microcode, and your particular CPU, it's updated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your microcode is up-to-date, checking it on my personal machine gives the same version and date running 19.10. That would be the proper way to update it other than using apt update.

Comment: C then why I keep getting this version "[    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xca, date = 2019-10-03" when instead I should have this version "20191115"

Comment: Where are you getting that date revision from?

Comment: It depends on the CPU, and the CPU vendor.  Only the newest CPUs will get the latest version. All I get is `revision 0xa0b, date = 2010-09-28`, and the CPU is 10 years old. Apparently, Intel doesn't release updates for this particular model, SU2300.